# Individual or single head for dynamic array of linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, dynamic-arrays

If I were to make a dynamic array of linked list would each index have it's own head or would there be one single head for the entire array? I don't have code yet since i'm just working on pseudocode right now, but i'll give an example..

1. Make a struct called arrayNode with a next pointer and an int data
2. Declare and initialize the array of list  ->    arrayNode *array[size] = new arrayNode[size]
3. Make a head ->  arrayNode *head

Now, if I want to put a value into array[0], i check if head is NULL and if it is, I make that value the head

1. array[0] = new arrayNode(value)
2. head = array[0]

I'm not sure if that's even the correct way of doing it, but I think it is....Anyways, if it is, then what about array[1]? Is head still NULL for it? Or do I have to declare a different head for each index??

if it isn't the correct way, then back to square one.

Thanks

Comment: Linked lists do not normally have random access, so no need for array.

Comment: Well, I just need access to the index i'm storing the linked list, not necessarily the linked list itself. I'm trying to build an adjacency list and this is how I figure it would(could) work.

Answer (score 0):

As you have commented that you are trying to build an adjacency list. So in that case:

- Make an array of the size equals the number of vertices in graph
- For each vertex in the graph use a separate head

If size number of vertices in graph are not fixed then:

- Create a new class which will have information about a vertex
- Overload index i.e. [] operator to provide the correct node. But back in the code of [] operator overloading, you have to manage the logic.